# Layout box as inset in wide display, and in-line in narrow (mobile) display

Tags: html, css

In my homepage I have some main text, and I want to add a small box with some side text (site new or whatever). I want to use the same HTML, style with media queries to achieve the below layouts (sorry for crude MSPaint mockup). **Note**: In desktop layout, main text should reflow around sidetext.

HTML:

```
<article>main text main text...</article>
<aside>side text side text...</aside>
<div id="more">more stuff more stuff...</div>
```

I've tried:

- styling `aside {float: right}` - but it's to the right of `more`, and I want `#article`
- moving `aside` before `article` - then `float` styling looks right in regular layout, but in mobile the `aside` appears first.

[image: desired layout]

Comment: is your goal the layout on these images?

Comment: Yes, that's the layout I want to achieve. Of course, in the regular layout, main text shold reflow around the side text, not be under it.

Comment: I think you must add this information (main text shold reflow around the side text, not be under it) on the question.

Comment: Added, also clarified mockup image.

Comment: @Jonathan Is it for you allowed to have the aside inside the `<article>` element?

Comment: Yes, I can change the HTML freely. The above was just to give an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the perfect result using the `flex-direction: column-reverse;` property on small screens. **Update:** Alternatively, CSS `order` / `-webkit-order` could've been used instead.

[**FINAL PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqGPLv?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: lavender;
}

#container {
 position: relative;  
}

#a {
  vertical-align: top;
  background: gold;  
}

#b {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: tomato;
  width: 40%;
}

#second {
  background: yellowgreen;  
}

@media (max-width: 740px){
  #container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  
#a {
  width: 100%;
}
  
#b {
  margin-top: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id=container><div id=b>side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text side text.</div><div id=a>text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text main text.</div></div>

<p id=second>more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff </p>
```

Comment: Nice. I'd prefer a solution which doesn't duplicate the "main text" content, since that would be periodically edited manually by someone else, and they're likely to forget updating both copies.

Comment: I'll go with the second version. I guess I could duplicate the main text with javascript, but that would be overengineering.

Comment: Im glad to tell you I found a solution without any tricks using `flex-direction: column-reverse;` to invert the divs position on small screen devices. Check my lastest update please;

Comment: Works awesomely! I already implemented the non-wrapping sidebar solution, so I'll keep that. Wish I could accept and upvote again.